# Парсинг html помощь

Tags: c#, парсер

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var html = CQ.CreateFromUrl("https://www.liveinternet.ru/rating/ru/auto/");
        CQ cq = CQ.Create(html);
    }
```

Как продолжить с помощью данной библиотеки?
Нужно именно с этого сайта спарсить все заголовки и так на всех страницах.
Без примера никак не пойму(

Comment: Вопрос должен быть подробным: не хватает информации какую библиотеку Вы используете, какую HTML структуру пытаетесь распарсить и т.д. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: using CsQuery
Сайт, который пытаюсь распарсить указан в коде.

Comment: Прочитать докуметнацию к библиотеке

Comment: Хорошие советы Когда спрашиваешь про механику и просишь показать на примере, а тебя отсылают читать библиотеку и про html. По селекторам он ничего не заберёт, классов у тега, где сам текст - нет. А про сбор со всех страниц уже молчу.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых почитайте про [HTML](https://metanit.com/web/html5/).
Во-вторых почитайте про [JS](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/).

В-третьих используйте селектор `.text` - он выберет все строки из страницы.

Подробнее прочитать про библиотеку CsQuery можно [тут](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

Пример сбора через селектор через JS:
[image: test]

Если нужен тег выше - просто нужно идти по владельцу.

Comment: Хорошие советы
Когда спрашиваешь про механику и просишь показать на примере, а тебя отсылают читать библиотеку и про html.
По селекторам он ничего не заберёт, классов у тега, где сам текст - нет.
А про сбор со всех страниц уже молчу.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Тэг "a" находится в тэге div.text.
Но какой именно командой собрать все div, а потом из всех div собрать внутр. тэги a вместе с текстом.

Comment: Не в ту сторону вы смотрите, ох не в ту... Посмотрите внимательно для начала как работает сайт, изучите его и уж потом используйте разные библиотеки, если они там нужны. К примеру указанный сайт подгружает динамически данные при помощи простого GET запроса [на этот адрес](https://www.liveinternet.ru/rating/ru/auto/today.tsv?page=1). Все, остается только распарсить tsv файл и вытянуть от туда нужное. А страницы, тут еще проще - вверху файла пишет сколько всего строк в таблице, за раз сайт выдает 30 результатов, значит делаем `10419/30=347.3`, а значит у нас всего 348 страниц. Все, делаем цикл.